# show link with if/else and selected option

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I have been struggeling with this for a couple of hours and my head is exploding at this point. My programming skills are very low, so this should be an easy one for you.

I want to use an if/else statement with a selected option from a select menu to show a specific link. Say, when I select option1 from a select menu I want to show link1 and so on.

I searched a lot of topics and found several solutions, but non of them helped me, so please help me!

The HTML code I got so far:

```
<select name="package_select">
<option value="">Select package</option>
<option value="one">One listing</option>
<option value="two">Two listings</option>
</select>
```

And my PHP code:

```
<?php
$package = $_GET['package_select']; echo $package;

if ( $package == "one" ) { ?> 
first link

<?php }
else if ( $package == "two" ) { ?>
second link

<?php } else { ?>
do nothing...

<?php } ?>
```

I am probably missing something, but I don't know what...

Thank you so much!

Comment: Where do you want to show the link?

Comment: Isn't this already doing what you want? You just have to replace the plain text with the link you want to show.

Comment: Just below the select field (on the same page)

Comment: Than you have to place that PHP code just below the select.

Comment: @putvande no, it always shows 'do nothing...' even if I select one of the other values

Comment: Can you show your form as well? Maybe you have `method="post"`?

Comment: @putvande Yeah I know, but the problem is that it always shows 'do nothing...' and not one of the other options

Comment: Yes, you mentioned that already.. can you show your form

Comment: Just `<form action="" id="package_pick">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your form is using GET as the method.

```
<? PHP

$package = $_GET['package_select'];

          if ($package == 'one') {

              echo "Link 1"; 

            } else if ($package == 'two') {

              echo "Link 2";

            } else {

              echo "No Links";

            }



?>
```

Form Code

```
<form action="filename.php" method="get" id="packageForm" >

    <select name="package_select">
        <option value="">Select package</option>
        <option value="one">One listing</option>
        <option value="two">Two listings</option>
    </select>

    <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: Why does the select need an ID? Your PHP code won't do anything... In fact.. it will be an error.

Comment: Corrected my code - a select of course doesn't need an ID.

Comment: @MichaelBellamy Thanks, this works! But this code redirects me to another page. I can change filename.php to the same page, but I don't want to reload the page, just want to show the link (actually a button) at once when an option is selected. Any solution?

Comment: Rather than using PHP, if you don't want the page to load take a look at using jQuery and a function called .change().

The documentation is here with an example: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: @MichaelBellamy Thanks Michael, isn't it possible with PHP? I am so close now with the solution you provided me

Comment: The only way to run PHP code without refreshing the page is to use AJAX.  Have a look here for an example. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using jquery, and it works perfectly! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of get, try the post method:

```
$_POST['package_select']; 

<?php
<select name="package_select">
<option value="one">Select package</option>
<option value="two">One listing</option>
<option value="three">Two listings</option>
</select>


switch($_POST['package_select']){
case 'one':
 echo "link 1";
break;
case 'two':
 echo "link 2";
break;
case 'three':
 echo "link 3";
break;
default:
echo "no links";
}
?>
```

Comment: Your select has a name package_select not selectedValue

Comment: yes saw that and updated